# Generalized chainrule for Sobolev functions with a cut-off

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain and $f\in C^1(\bar\Omega \times (0,g(x)),[0,1])$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ increasing and $g(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ continuous (maybe better, Lipschitz?). I want to consider for $u\in H^1(\Omega)$, $u(x)\in[0,g(x)]$ for almost every $x$ the composition $f(x,u(x))$. However since $f$ is not $C^1$ on $\bar\Omega \times [0,g(x)]$ one does not a priori know whether such a function is in $H^1(\Omega)$. However if $f$ had this better regularity ($C^1$ on $\bar\Omega \times [0,g(x)]$) case, we would get the chainrule
$$ \nabla f(x,u)= f_x(x,u) + \partial_u f(x,u)\nabla u$$
simply by approximation.

However, for the case without so much regularity this won't work as Tomas pointed out. To this end we need to cut off the function $f$ at the levels say $1-\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$.

The "Stampacchia" lemma (i.e. $D(u-\varepsilon)_+ =Du \cdot 1_{u>\varepsilon}$) only cuts off on hyperplanes. But in this problem the cut-off level in space since $f$ depends on $x$.  Any suggestion?

Cutting-off at the levels $1-\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ I expect the derivative to be

$$\nabla f_\varepsilon(x,u)= 1_{\{\varepsilon<f(x,u)<1-\varepsilon\}}(f_x(x,u) +\partial_uf(x,u) \nabla u)$$

Potentially, we can write $f_\varepsilon(x,u)=(g\circ f)(x,u)$ with $g(a)=(\max\{1-\varepsilon,a\}-\varepsilon)_+ +\varepsilon$.

Without $x$-dependence of $f$ I can prove this with the Chainrule for Sobolev-functions since $f$ is Lipschitz and maps from $\mathbb{R}to\mathbb{R}$. Then in the chainrule the term $f_x$ vanishes. In the case with $x$-dependence the problem is that the set $\{f^{-1}(1-\varepsilon)\}$ is not anymore a single point but a curve/surface.

Check the second comment of Tomas and my answer for a good example.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $f$ is not $C^1$ in $u$?

Comment: sorry, if $u$ can attain the calues $\{0,1\}$ I am not allowd to apply the chain rule. I corrected it above

Comment: I don't think this is true. Take for example any functions $f:\overline{\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ and define $g(x,t)=f(x)+h(t)$, where $h\in C^1(0,1)$, is increasing, but it is not in $L^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: to this end I want to cut off the bad parts of $h$, say define $h_\varepsilon(t)=(\max\{h(1-\varepsilon),h(t)\}-\varepsilon)_+ +\varepsilon$. Then i can differentiate $h_\varepsilon(u)$ with $\nabla h_\varepsilon(u)= h_\varepsilon'(u)\nabla u$

Comment: I just gave you a counter example. You need to ask more on $f$, for example the derivative with respect to the last variable is bounded. It is the same as Stampacchia theorem.

Comment: Hey Tomas, i just realised I did not choose correct spaces. Maybe me intention becomes now clearer (now it makes more sense to cut-off at $0$ and $1$ since it is in the image of $f$.) Essentially i want to cut off $f$ so that i don't see the values where the function is not differentiable. I'm sorry for the previous mistakes. Do you still think that then the proof is the same as of the Stampacchia theorem?

Comment: @ Tomas, i changed the question again a bit. Now your counterexample is really a good example on what i want to do.

Comment: You can take your $g$ constant, for example, $g(x)=1$ for all $x$. Then we can adpapt a little bit my example to get another counter example. For example, in my example, we can ask that $h\in C([0,1])\cap C^1(0,1)$ but $h'\notin L^1$.

Comment: I fear there is a misunderstading. I know that a chain rule as above will not work. That's why I want to cut off $f$ or $h$ at the critical points. To this end I introduced the $\varepsilon$. You could also put it in the following way to a again generalized problem. If $f:R^{n+1}\to R$ is "piecewise$ C^1$. (This is achieved by cutting off $f$ as in my question). Is then $f(x,u(x))\in H^1(\Omega)$ for $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and does a Chain-rule hold?

Comment: Take $g(x)=1$. Define $f(x,t)=v(x)+h(x)$ where $v\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ and $h\in C([0,1])\cap C^1(0,1)$ with $h$ increasing and $h'\notin L^1(\Omega)$. Now I am saying that you can find $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that the derivative of $v(x)+h(u(x))$ does not belong to $L^1(\Omega)$. Is this wat your want, if not probably I am not understanding you questions, sorry.

Comment: you are right, but this is not what I want :) I think I'll post a more precise question later. Sorry for my bad question then :(